# how to build a parser with antlr4 target golang without visitors and walkers

Tags: go, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to write a small parser with golang target, but not using visitors or walkers, but I am not able to find any sample code to build my parser upon.

For example, the following is the grammar code which I am trying to replicate with golang:

```
# Expr.g4:
grammar Expr;
@header {
}
@parser::members {

def eval(self, left, op, right):
    if   ExprParser.MUL == op.type:
        return left * right
    elif ExprParser.DIV == op.type:
        return left / right
    elif ExprParser.ADD == op.type:
        return left + right
    elif ExprParser.SUB == op.type:
        return left - right
    else:
        return 0
}

stat:   e NEWLINE           {print($e.v);}
    |   ID '=' e NEWLINE    {self.memory[$ID.text] = $e.v}
    |   NEWLINE                   
    ;

e returns [int v]
    : a=e op=('*'|'/') b=e  {$v = self.eval($a.v, $op, $b.v)}
    | a=e op=('+'|'-') b=e  {$v = self.eval($a.v, $op, $b.v)}
    | INT                   {$v = $INT.int}    
    | ID
      {
id = $ID.text
$v = self.memory.get(id, 0)
      }
    | '(' e ')'             {$v = $e.v}       
    ; 
MUL : '*' ;
DIV : '/' ;
ADD : '+' ;
SUB : '-' ;
ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;      // match identifiers
INT :   [0-9]+ ;         // match integers
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;     // return newlines to parser (is end-statement signal)
WS  :   [ \t]+ -> skip ; // toss out whitespace
```

And this is the python tester code for it:

```
# test_expr.py:
import sys
from antlr4 import *
from antlr4.InputStream import InputStream

from ExprLexer import ExprLexer
from ExprParser import ExprParser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ExprParser(None)
    parser.buildParseTrees = False
    parser.memory = {}  # how to add this to generated constructor?

    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    lineno = 1

    while line != '':
        line = line.strip()

        istream = InputStream(line + "\n")
        lexer = ExprLexer(istream)
        lexer.line = lineno
        lexer.column = 0
        token_stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
        parser.setInputStream(token_stream)
        parser.stat()

        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        lineno += 1
```

Can anybody please post a sample golang code which is equivalent to the above python and inlined code?

Comment: Could you post your own Go implementation and ask a specific question about it? Right now, you're really just asking someone else to write the entire thing for you.

Comment: Problem is, I dont have any sample code on which to base my own 1st version. For example, corresponding to the definition of eval() and its usage in "$v = self.eval(...)", what class would the eval function belong to, etc? I am not looking for somebody to write my code for me, I am just looking for a sample code on which to base my own parser. If something like that exists somewhere (even for a different grammar), if you can just point me to that link, I can start working based on that.

Comment: ANTLR 4 features visitors and listeners so you probably can only find typical samples like that. Why must you stick to actions (the things in {})? That's the legacy of previous ANTLR versions (2/3), so only old samples use that.

Comment: Is there a link where I can get the golang equivalent of all the Java examples of the book? That will be enough for me to get started on this.

Comment: @BartKiers: I took a first cut at writing the code, and faced a compiler problem when accessing the values returned by the grammar components. I posted a more specific question on that topic - 64842665. Can you please help with that? After I cross that hurdle, I may come back to this question again.